# Ejecutar una aplicación de Visual Studio en Windows 10

Tags: visual-studio, windows10

Ya tengo el archivo ejecutable de la aplicación que realice en Visual Studio pero al momento de instalarla en mi máquina que tiene Windows 10 no la instala y me dice que tengo que hablar con el proveedor pero si la instalo en otra versión anterior a Windows 10 sí lo instala.

¿Cómo puedo solucionar esto?

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: En el Visor de Eventos o Event Viewer (si lo tienes instalado en inglés) ¿no se registra algo? Es decir, algo como el detalle del por qué no se puede instalar. A lo mejor eso nos podría dar más detalle de lo que está pasando.

Comment: Puedes poner la imagen del error? o el texto del error??

Comment: hola @Flxtr si al desplegar los detalles no me muestra ningun error

Comment: si @CristinaCarrascoAngulo ahorita subo la imagen

Comment: Gracias @karol :-)

Comment: listo crstina ya agregue la imagen

Answer (score 1):

Prueba cambiando la compartibilidad del ejecutable.

1. Click derecho con el mouse.
2. Seleccionar **Propiedades**.
3. Dentro de **Propiedades** seleccionar la solapa ***Compartibilidad***.
4. Seleccionar el **check** de ***"Ejecutar este programa en modo de compartibilidad para:"*** y seleccionas la versión de **Windows** que desees.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

5. Aplicas y Aceptas cambios.
6. Intenta nuevamente instalarlo.

Comment: hola gracias por responder am segui los pasos pero solo llega hasta el windows 8 y yo tengo el 10

Comment: Por eso es para ejecutarlo como si fuese un windows 8 así tengas windows 10, para eso es la compartibilidad ejecutar programas como  si tuvieras una versión anterior del sistema

Comment: ah ps ya le puse ahi en compatibilidad windows 8 y aun asi no lo instala

Comment: Has probado también ejecutarlo como administrador??

Comment: si tambien y no

Comment: también ya intentaste ejecutarlo en otra maquina con w10?

Comment: si tambien y me marca el mismo error, solo si lo instalo en otra vesion de windows si funciona

Comment: Que tiene tu aplicacion desarrollada?

Comment: y como generaste el Ejecutable?

Comment: lo genere en visual studio pero no lo instala en windows 10 pero si en versiones anteriores

Comment: ah ok gracias .......